# Cookie issue in cakephp ajax request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, cookies

I am implementing Ajax login using auth component in my cakephp app. Everything is working fine except remember me.

I am trying to set cookie using Cookie component but seems it's not sending cookie with response.

I have tried other setting domain, path and user agent check false in session variable but it didn't work.

If I use `setcookie` method then it's sending cookie in response (but I need cakephp cookie as I am saving array in cookie)

Below is code that I am using:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->Cookie->path = '/';
    $this->Cookie->httpOnly = true;


    if (!$this->Auth->loggedIn() && $this->Cookie->read('rememberMe')) {

        $cookie = $this->Cookie->read('rememberMe');

        $user = $this->User->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'User.username' => $cookie['username'],
                'User.password' => $cookie['password']
            )
        ));

        if ($user && !$this->Auth->login($user['User'])) {
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'logout')); // destroy session &   cookie
        } else {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl()); // redirect to Auth.redirect if it is set, else to Auth.loginRedirect ('/users/userhome') if it is set, else to /
        }
    }
}
```

Here is login function code:

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    Croogo::dispatchEvent('Controller.Users.loginSuccessful', $this);
    if ($this->request->data['User']['remember_me'] == 1) {
        $cookieTime = "2 months"; // You can do e.g: 1 week, 17 weeks, 14 days
        // remove "remember me checkbox"
        unset($this->request->data['User']['remember_me']);
        // hash the user's password
        $this->request->data['User']['password'] = $this->Auth->password($this->request->data['User']['password']);
        // write the cookie
        $this->Cookie->write('rememberMe', $this->request->data['User'], true, $cookieTime);

    }
    $response['status'] = 'success';
    $response['redirect_url'] = Router::url(array('action' => 'dashboard'), true);
    $response['action'] = 'login';
    $response['message'] = __d('sharbook', 'You have logged in successfully. Please stand by...');
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Please help me to fix issue.

Comment: Have you checked your coockie in $_COOCKIE ?

Comment: You shouldn't drop in images without an explanation of what they are showing! The image shows that the response contains a cookie, however that's the session cookie. ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: @ndm I have removed image but don't know why it's showing here(it was giving validation error that you need at least 10 reputation) and i will take care about version thing. Thanks

Comment: Somebody added it for you. I didn't wanted to say that you should remove it, but that in order to avoid confusion it would be good if you'd add a little explanation that the response cookie that is being shown there is the session cookie, and _not_ the cookie defined by the cookie component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing, you should enabled debug mode in your application (`Configure::write('debug', 2)`), or check the debug logs, then you'd see that you are getting a "*Cannot modify header information - headers already sent*" warning.

### Do not manually output data using `echo` or the like

Except for session cookies which are being sent immediately when a session is started, normal cookies are queued in the `CakeResponse` object (`$this->response` in your controller) until [**after the controller action has been executed**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.3/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php#L172), so doing an `echo` in your controller action will cause headers and data to be sent, and therefore the cookie headers cannot be sent anymore.

### Use a view or the `CakeResponse` object instead

Simple fix, either use the [**JSON view**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) functionality (recommended)

```
class YourController extends AppController {
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    // ...

    public function login() {
        // ...

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            // ...

            $response['status'] = 'success';
            $response['redirect_url'] = Router::url(array('action' => 'dashboard'), true);
            $response['action'] = 'login';
            $response['message'] = __d('sharbook', 'You have logged in successfully. Please stand by...');

            $this->set('response', $response);
            $this->set('_serialize', array('response'));
        }
    }
}
```

or properly set the response body on [**the response object**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakeresponse)

```
$this->response->body(json_encode($response));
$this->response->type('json');
```

so that the data is being sent by `CakeResponse::send()` (which will properly send the cookie headers first) after the action has been dispatched.

Comment: Thanks @ndm, JSON view fixed issue. :)